# Setting a global variable based on a value in params in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Rails 5.2
```

I would like to setup a global variable, available to all controllers. This would be set, based on the value of one of the params. I tried doing this:

```
controllers/application_controller.rb

before_action :set_book_author

def set_book_author 
  @book_author = params[:book_author] if params.has_key?(:book_author)
end
```

But since the rest call is going to /book_authors/:book_author, application_controller.rb, does not see it first.

Is there a way to do this?

## Example of how I understand session to be unreliable:

```
class Location
  def initialize(ip)
    @location = location_request(ip)  
  end
end

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_location

  def set_location(user_ip)
    session[:user_location] = Location.new(user_ip)
  end
end
```

As soon as I am no longer using Location, the app will raise an exception, if I try to use session[:user_location]

Comment: Are you sure you want to set a global variable and you don't want to set a `session` value?

Comment: I thought that session values are not reliable in Rails

Comment: Do you have that parameter named the same way in all affected routes?

Comment: @vafsed yes, it is named the same in all affected routes

Comment: *"I thought that session values are not reliable in Rails"* - Why would you think that? "not reliable" in what way? Do you have a reference?

Comment: I suggest rewording your question to avoid term 'global variable', because these are evil in most cases, and also they are not what you describe.

Comment: @jvillian See the edit to my question

Comment: IMO, that doesn't look like `session` is unreliable. It looks like an unreliable use of `session`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your code looks like it should work fine, but make sure that all your affected controllers inherit from `ApplicationController` (that's the default in generator, but check just to be on the safe side) and param name is what you provided and is the same in all affected actions (rails nested `resources` will produce `book_author_id`, not `book_author`).

Other thought - you may not need to fetch data from params for every action of every controller (because later you may want to do a db query there or something similar), so it's better to have a helper method with memoization (this will be accessible from both controller and views):

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  helper_method def book_author
    raise("No book author in params (change this to `return` once confirmed ok)") unless params.has_key?(:book_author)

    @book_author ||= begin
      # here goes the fetching code, that returns result:
      params[:book_author]
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: This looks like it might work, with the memorization option